# View of right-angled-triangle from a constant-velocity relative observer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Suppose I have a picture of a right angled triangle drawn in the X-Y plane,

[image]

and a man whose velocity relative to the to picture is $0.4c\hat{x}-0.4c\hat{y}$.

Will the angle $\theta$ that the man will measure still be 90 degrees?

---

I tried to solve this problem, but I am not sure whether my solution is correct.

Using the Lorentz transformation, I have calculated the location of each vertex as seen by the moving man,

Then I made a vector out of each edge (the result for each edge was actually the original vector divided by the same $\gamma$ since the velocities are of the same amount in each axis)

and by using the dot product I received the angle (which was still 90).

Other friends have received that the angle is about 102 degrees, I am not sure how can that be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: triangle ABC, A on the right angle, M the middle of BC, MA the direction of propagation. What are the length of BC and of MA , when the triangle is at rest and in motion ? likely 102° ...

Comment: Each edge is 12.

Comment: no, just compute their relativistic lengths and then the value of the new angle in A, remembering that it is an isocele triangle  by symmetry of BA and CA. Only MA changes , BC being perpendicular to the motion.

Comment: Wow I think I've got it. Thank you very much! (If you'd like you can post an answer and I'll accept that).

Comment: post it yourself, it's your work. Do nice presentation to get more upvotes :)